# Substitute in HMS for GTM enhanced ecommerce Measuring Purchases

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Is any Substitute in HMS like GTM enhanced ecommerce Measuring Purchases

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced e-commerce function in the Google Analytics: Universal Analytics template is supported, allowing you to easily track user interactions with your product, including product display, product click, product details view, adding your product to the shopping cart, checkout, transaction, and refund.

Please refer below document link, this will guide you in depth:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-condition-management-example-0000001079066119-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001079066119__section1557062603218

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate HMS - Dynamic Tag Manager (DTM) to track events and monitor your marketing activity data.

Please refer this link for detail procedure of creating a tag https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-tag-management-operation-procedure-0000001076930394-V5

This video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7OuFZNTUIQ explains how to integrate DTM and update tag configuration easily and securely.